# Write to different file in function of the value of a column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that I use for work and I create XML files from the data in the Excel file. The first column of the worksheet is named "modifier" and the value in this column may be "create" "delete" or "modify". I am currently writing in the same file indifferently from which is the modifier. What I want to do is create three different files and write them in function of the modifier.
So if the modifier is "create" write to Create.xml, if the modifier is "delete" write to Delete.xml and if the modifier is "modify" write to Modify.xml.

This is my VBA script (for some reason I can't format all the code as code):

```
Sub Externas3g2gxml() 

Dim SpecAtt As String

SpecAtt = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExternalGSMCell").Cells(2, 1)


On Error Resume Next
    MkDir ThisWorkbook.Path & "\NR_Scripts_"
On Error GoTo 0

Const ModifRange As String = "B2:B5000"

    Dim Modif As range

    For Each Modif In range(ModifRange)
        If Modif.Value = "create" Then

           Sheets("ExternalGSMCell").Select

            strExt3g2gCreate = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\NR_Scripts_\Create_ExternalGSMCell.xml"

            f = FreeFile

            i = 4

            Open strExt3g2gCreate For Output As #f

            Version = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExternalGSMCell").Cells(2, 21)
            Print #f, "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""no""?>"
            Print #f, "<bulkCmConfigDataFile xmlns:un=""utranNrm.xsd"" xmlns:xn=""genericNrm.xsd"" xmlns:gn=""geranNrm.xsd"" xmlns=""configData.xsd"" xmlns:es=""EricssonSpecificAttributes.17.09.xsd"">"
            Print #f, "<fileHeader fileFormatVersion=""32.615 V4.5"" vendorName=""Ericsson""/>"
            Print #f, "<configData>"
            Print #f, "<xn:SubNetwork id=""ONRM_ROOT_MO_R"">"

            While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExternalGSMCell").Cells(i, 2) <> ""
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExternalGSMCell").Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then

            Print #f, "             <gn:ExternalGsmCell id=""" & Cells(i, 2).Value & """ modifier=""create"">"
            Print #f, "                 <gn:attributes>"
            Print #f, "                     <gn:userLabel>" & Cells(i, 2).Value & "</gn:userLabel>"
            Print #f, "                     <gn:cellIdentity>" & Cells(i, 3).Value & "</gn:cellIdentity>"
            Print #f, "                     <gn:bcchFrequency>" & Cells(i, 4).Value & "</gn:bcchFrequency>"
            Print #f, "                     <gn:ncc>" & Cells(i, 5).Value & "</gn:ncc>"
            Print #f, "                     <gn:bcc>" & Cells(i, 6).Value & "</gn:bcc>"
            Print #f, "                     <gn:lac>" & Cells(i, 7).Value & "</gn:lac>"
            Print #f, "                     <gn:mcc>" & Cells(i, 9).Value & "</gn:mcc>"
            Print #f, "                     <gn:mnc>" & Cells(i, 10).Value & "</gn:mnc>"
            Print #f, "                 </gn:attributes>"
            Print #f, "                 <xn:VsDataContainer id=""" & Cells(i, 2).Value & """ modifier=""create"">"
            Print #f, "                     <xn:attributes>"
            Print #f, "                         <xn:vsDataType>vsDataExternalGsmCell</xn:vsDataType>"
            Print #f, "                         <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes.17.09</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>"
            Print #f, "                         <es:vsDataExternalGsmCell>"
            Print #f, "                             <es:maxTxPowerUl>" & Cells(i, 11).Value & "</es:maxTxPowerUl>"
            Print #f, "                             <es:qRxLevMin>" & Cells(i, 12).Value & "</es:qRxLevMin>"
            Print #f, "                             <es:individualOffset>0</es:individualOffset>"

            Print #f, "                             <es:mncLength>2</es:mncLength>"
            Print #f, "                             <es:bandIndicator>2</es:bandIndicator>"
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExternalGSMCell").Cells(i, 8) <> "" Then
            Print #f, "                             <es:rac>" & Cells(i, 8).Value & "</es:rac>"
            Else
            Print #f, "                             <es:rac>1</es:rac>"
            End If
            Print #f, "                         </es:vsDataExternalGsmCell>"
            Print #f, "                     </xn:attributes>"
            Print #f, "                 </xn:VsDataContainer>"
            Print #f, "             </gn:ExternalGsmCell>"
            End If

                    i = i + 1
                    m = m + 1

            Wend
            Print #f, "     </xn:SubNetwork>"
            Print #f, "   </configData>"
            Print #f, "  <fileFooter dateTime=""2017""/>"
            Print #f, "</bulkCmConfigDataFile>"
            Close f


        Else
            If Modif.Value = "update" Then
            strExt3g2gUpdate = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\NR_Scripts_\Update_ExternalGSMCell.xml"

            f = FreeFile

            i = 4
            m = 4

            Open strExt3g2gUpdate For Output As #f

            Version = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExternalGSMCell").Cells(2, 21)
            Print #f, "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""no""?>"
            Print #f, "<bulkCmConfigDataFile xmlns:un=""utranNrm.xsd"" xmlns:xn=""genericNrm.xsd"" xmlns:gn=""geranNrm.xsd"" xmlns=""configData.xsd"" xmlns:es=""EricssonSpecificAttributes.17.09.xsd"">"
            Print #f, "<fileHeader fileFormatVersion=""32.615 V4.5"" vendorName=""Ericsson""/>"
            Print #f, "<configData>"
            Print #f, "<xn:SubNetwork id=""ONRM_ROOT_MO_R"">"

            While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExternalGSMCell").Cells(i, 2) <> ""
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExternalGSMCell").Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then

            Print #f, "             <gn:ExternalGsmCell id=""" & Cells(i, 2).Value & """ modifier=""update"">"
            Print #f, "                 <gn:attributes>"
            Print #f, "                     <gn:userLabel>" & Cells(i, 2).Value & "</gn:userLabel>"
            Print #f, "                     <gn:cellIdentity>" & Cells(i, 3).Value & "</gn:cellIdentity>"
            Print #f, "                     <gn:bcchFrequency>" & Cells(i, 4).Value & "</gn:bcchFrequency>"
            Print #f, "                     <gn:ncc>" & Cells(i, 5).Value & "</gn:ncc>"
            Print #f, "                     <gn:bcc>" & Cells(i, 6).Value & "</gn:bcc>"
            Print #f, "                     <gn:lac>" & Cells(i, 7).Value & "</gn:lac>"
            Print #f, "                     <gn:mcc>" & Cells(i, 9).Value & "</gn:mcc>"
            Print #f, "                     <gn:mnc>" & Cells(i, 10).Value & "</gn:mnc>"
            Print #f, "                 </gn:attributes>"
            Print #f, "                 <xn:VsDataContainer id=""" & Cells(i, 2).Value & """ modifier=""update"">"
            Print #f, "                     <xn:attributes>"
            Print #f, "                         <xn:vsDataType>vsDataExternalGsmCell</xn:vsDataType>"
            Print #f, "                         <xn:vsDataFormatVersion>EricssonSpecificAttributes.17.09</xn:vsDataFormatVersion>"
            Print #f, "                         <es:vsDataExternalGsmCell>"
            Print #f, "                             <es:maxTxPowerUl>" & Cells(i, 11).Value & "</es:maxTxPowerUl>"
            Print #f, "                             <es:qRxLevMin>" & Cells(i, 12).Value & "</es:qRxLevMin>"
            Print #f, "                             <es:individualOffset>0</es:individualOffset>"

            Print #f, "                             <es:mncLength>2</es:mncLength>"
            Print #f, "                             <es:bandIndicator>2</es:bandIndicator>"
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ExternalGSMCell").Cells(i, 8) <> "" Then
            Print #f, "                             <es:rac>" & Cells(i, 8).Value & "</es:rac>"
            Else
            Print #f, "                             <es:rac>1</es:rac>"
            End If
            Print #f, "                         </es:vsDataExternalGsmCell>"
            Print #f, "                     </xn:attributes>"
            Print #f, "                 </xn:VsDataContainer>"
            Print #f, "             </gn:ExternalGsmCell>"
            End If

                    i = i + 1
                    m = m + 1

            Wend
            Print #f, "     </xn:SubNetwork>"
            Print #f, "   </configData>"
            Print #f, "  <fileFooter dateTime=""2017""/>"
            Print #f, "</bulkCmConfigDataFile>"
            Close f
            End If
        End If
        Next

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome! it would be easier to help you with your macro if you posted it...  :-) Check out the [tour] and [mcve]

Comment: @ashleedawg I just posted my macro. Thank you.

Comment: I did not go through your code, but using those names is not a good practice. Those names could be reserved names and can cause your problems with no or a misleading error description. I suggest that you choose different names for example instead of Delete.xml choose XML_Delete_File.xml

Comment: Thanks, I don't use those names. It was just an example.